# How do I write this logic of C#'s datetime difference in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this logic in my C# code which gives me time difference between two times

**Example inputs are:** '12:00 AM' - '11:15 AM' gives 45 minutes.

```
DateTime startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(startTimeHH + ":" + startTimeMM + " " + startTimeAMPM);
DateTime endTime = Convert.ToDateTime(endTimeHH + ":" + endTimeMM + " " + endTimeAMPM);
DateTime breakTime = Convert.ToDateTime(breakTimeHH + ":" + breakTimeMM);

TimeSpan hours = endTime.Subtract(startTime);
hours = hours.Subtract(breakTime.TimeOfDay);
```

I referred some MSDN docs datetime functions in SQL server but couldn't find these functions which can give me time from input as `12:00 PM`

However now I need to move this piece now into SQL server. How do I write it?

**Example inputs are:** '12:00 AM' - '11:15 AM' **won't** return 45 it **will** return 75 (it contains 15 as 25)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to get what looks like a .NET TimeSpan:

```
declare @startTimeHH char(2) = '10',
        @startTimeMM char(2) = '30',
        @startTimeAMPM char(2) = 'AM',
        @endTimeHH char(2) = '12',
        @endTimeMM char(2) = '00',
        @endTimeAMPM char(2) = 'PM',
        @breakTimeHH char(2) = '01',
        @breakTimeMM char(2) = '15',
        @startTime DateTime, 
        @endTime DateTime, 
        @breakTime DateTime, 
        @result Time

set @startTime = cast ((@startTimeHH + ':' + @startTimeMM + ' ' + @startTimeAMPM) as Time);
set @endTime = cast ((@endTimeHH + ':' + @endTimeMM + ' ' + @endTimeAMPM) as Time);
set @breakTime = cast ((@breakTimeHH + ':' + @breakTimeMM) as Time);

set @result = @endTime - @startTime - @breakTime
select cast(@result as CHAR(8))
```

The result is `00:15:00`

Comment: Hi schellack, I like your answer. However it was my mistake. Please see my edit. It will not return 45 but will return 75. It assumes 15 as 25. It returns  out of 100 not 60. Can you please modify your answer?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out on my own. This one works perfectly: select CAST(LEFT(cast(@result as CHAR(8)),2) + '.' + CAST(CAST( CAST(RIGHT(LEFT(cast(@result as CHAR(8)),5),2) as CHAR(2)) as float) * 100/60 as varchar(2)) as float)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].#events (            
    [StartTime] time NULL,            
    [EndTime] time NULL )            

INSERT INTO #events            
VALUES            
('08:00', '08:30'),            
('08:30', '08:00'),            
('09:00', '10:00'),            
('15:00', '16:30')  

select  convert(time, dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, StartTime, EndTime), 0))  
From #events

drop table #events
```

### ResultSet

> 00:30:00.0000000 
>   23:30:00.0000000 
>   01:00:00.0000000 
>   01:30:00.0000000

Answer (score 0):

Use [**DateDiff**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function

[**DatePart**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420) will be handy, too

Answer (score 0):

Here is some SQL that returns '45' (minutes)

```
DECLARE @Start DATETIME, @END DATETIME
SET @Start = '2009-05-02 10:00:50'
set @End = '2009-05-02 10:45:50'

    -- FYI
SELECT @start, @end

    -- returns 45
SELECT DateDiff(mi, @start, @end)
```